# Loading text file into MS ACCESS TABLE using Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I'm having some issues trying to load a tab delimited text file into an MS ACCESS database table using Delphi.

So far I have been able to create a new Access Database and table but when I try and load the data in I get an EOLeException with message:

'The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'FIELD1_FIELD2_FIELD3_...'

My code is as follows:

```
cs := 'insert into TABLENAME(FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6, FIELD7,      FIELD8, FIELD9, FIELD10, FIELD11, FIELD12, FIELD13, FIELD14, FIELD15) select * from [FILENAME.txt] in "' + EditJobLocation.Text + '"  "Text;HDR=Yes"';
ADOCommand2.CommandText := cs;
try
   ADOCommand2.Execute;
etc...
```

Not sure what the issue is but I think it has to do with the 'select *' part returning all the fields as one underscore delimited string.

I have been googling around trying to find some answers but have not yet found anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the "select *" seems the problem, the obvious question would be: have you already tried "select field1, field2, ... " instead?

Comment: Without looking into content of the FILENAME.txt, at first 2-3 lines, will be hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: try removing the `insert` part, leaving just the `select * from...` part e.g.

```
cs := 'select * from [FILENAME.txt] in "' + EditJobLocation.Text + '"  "Text;HDR=Yes"';
```

Use this revised SQL statement to open a recordset object. If it succeeds, examine the recordset's `Fields` collection: i.e. how many columns returned, their names, their ordinal positions, etc.

Hopefully this will identify whether the problem is fetching the data from the text file or whether it is with the insert action.

p.s. if you haven;t already, look into using a [`schema.ini`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file to gain better control on how Access 'sees' the text file's data in terms of columns and their data types.